# macOS/OSX Detect mouse event USB ID / Device Type

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to detect the current cursor's USB Unique ID or Device Type (tablet/touchpad/usb-mouse/...)

However the EventMonitor in OSX does not provide useful information, all USB devices return 0x0 in deviceID.

EventMonitor implementation:

```
NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask(mask: NSEventMask, handler block: (NSEvent) -> Void) -> AnyObject?
```

**Example**:

```
 eventMonitor = EventMonitor(mask: [.MouseMovedMask]) { [unowned self] event in
      print(event?.deviceID) // Returns 0x0 for USB Devices

    }
    eventMonitor?.start()
}
```

I need to distinguish or detect what device the user is currently using.

Comment: Where does the `EventMonitor` type come from?

Comment: It is just a `NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask`, forgot to mention that.